# The left creation operators on the Fock space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, tensor-products

Gelu Popescu has a big paper on multivariable generalizations of the numerical radius (Memoirs of the AMS, [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410492.pdf)). In page 8 of this memoirs I see the following paragraph:

[image]

> Are the operators $S_i$ commuting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $S_i(S_j1)=S_i(e_j)=e_i\otimes e_j$ and
$S_j(S_i1)=e_j\otimes e_i$. In $H\otimes H$, $e_i\otimes e_j\ne e_j
\otimes e_i$ unless $i= j$, so if $i\ne j$ then $S_iS_j\ne S_j S_i$.